# cakephp 2.8 Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /cake/.../FlashComponent.php on line 72

Tags: php, cakephp, flash-component

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /homepages/41/d117757366/htdocs/projects/pool/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/FlashComponent.php on line 72.

I get this error after reloading the page and after sending a form. Every time! ANY form. Everything is working when I don't reload the page.

Thanks for your help!

Andy

Comment: I always got this error in all 2.x versions...

Comment: Show us your method where you save form data. PHP version, server?

Comment: Thanks for comment. It is simply `if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $this->Contact->create();` ... `if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {` ... `}` `}`

Comment: PHP 5.6, 1&1 Hosting

Comment: do you have any if( something = something) around that? any $var += something? any other use of = <> && || .... ?

Comment: Just look at the source code, the error message tells you exactly where to look. It happens because the second argument of `FlashComponent::set()` is not an array. So check from where it is being invoked and fix it.

Comment: In line 72 of FlashComponent is `$options += $this->_defaultConfig;` and one line before the function `public function set($message, $options = array()) {` What shall i fix?